split comma seperate columns into rows
I am working on databricks 11.2 spark sql, i have table with two columns



Col1
Col2




1,2,3
a,b,c


1,2,3,4,5
a,b,c,d,e



Note

No.of items same between col1 and col2
for each row no of items might vary one row contains 3 comma seperate values , where as other row may contain 5 no of items.

Now using spark sql i need to split column values into row, the output should look like



Col1
Col2




1
a


2
b


3
c


1
a


2
b


3
c


4
d


5
e




You can try to use zip_with to match values with each other and then explode merged rows with lateral view
WITH merged_arrays AS (
  SELECT 
    zip_with(
      split(Col1, ','), 
      split(Col2, ','), 
      (a, b) -> struct(a AS col1, b AS col2)
    ) AS merged 
  FROM 
    original_table
) 
SELECT 
  merged_col.col1 AS Col1, 
  merged_col.col2 AS Col2 
FROM 
  merged_arrays LATERAL VIEW explode(merged) AS merged_col;

Output:
Col1    Col2
1   a
2   b
3   c
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e


Check below code.
SELECT
    INLINE(
        ARRAYS_ZIP(
            SPLIT(
                COL1,
                ','
            ),
            SPLIT(
                COL2,
                ','
            )
        )
    ) AS (COL1, COL2)
FROM VALUES ("1,2,3","a,b,c"),("1,2,3,4,5","a,b,c,d,e") AS (COL1, COL2)

+----+----+
|COL1|COL2|
+----+----+
|1   |a   |
|2   |b   |
|3   |c   |
|1   |a   |
|2   |b   |
|3   |c   |
|4   |d   |
|5   |e   |
+----+----+

